# Calculating match % and ranking according to that

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, approximation

I'm creating a website like where users will answer some yes/no questions set by me, up to them how many of those questions they want to answer. After a user submits his answer(s), he will be shown top 5 matches along with their match percentages. If two users have 10 common questions and their answers match for 8 of those questions then their match % will be 80%.

I can make this but my concern is about efficiency. A way of making this: If a user wants to see his top matches then match % (or match ratio) will be calculated for him vs every other user in the system. This will be stored in a temporary array. Array is sorted. Top 5 matches from the array are displayed.

Any less resource intensive way to calculate and show top matches?

Edit: If the top matches can be calculated without first calculating match percentages then i'm open to that.

Comment: Welcome to CS@SE. When [tagging questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), please read the tag descriptions: I don't see any quality/error limit in your problem statement justifying tag [tag:approximation]

Comment: (For best matches, *why* the detour via percentages?)

Comment: @greybeard Thanks. I've never learned approximation in CS but i'm open to approximate results if it makes doing ranking less resource intense.

Comment: @greybeard If the best matches can be calculated without first calculating match percentages then i'm open to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no algorithm that is significantly better than doing a pairwise comparison between all pairs of users.

You can, as you say, memoize (remember) the top-5 match for each user, so that you never have to recompute the top-5 for that user again in the future, but you'll still need to compare that user to each other user at least once.  Basically, each time a new user appears, you compare them to all other users, to compute their top-5 matches (and update the top-5 matches of other users by adding this user to the top-5 lists of other users where appropriate).

That's basically the brute-force algorithm.  I don't expect there to be an alternative that is better in practice.

---

In principle, there are a variety of methods.  One method is to use a [locality-sensitive hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing).  The simplest form of LSH is to choose a random subset of questions, then for each user extract their answers to those questions, hash that, and store the user in a bucket associated with the user's hash value.  Then two users who are very similar have a decent chance of ending up in the same bucket.  If you construct 100 such data structures, each with a different subset of questions, and if you choose the parameters right, you might have a decent chance of finding all of the top-5 matches in this way (along with some other extraneous matches, but those can be filtered out by doing a full comparison for each potential match).  However, this is pretty fiddly with respect to parameters, and if people tend to answer only some of the questions, I suspect it won't perform that well in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my "A way of making this",
Instead of array, building min heap of max 5 elements for top 5 matches is a better way. This heap will be populated when match %s are being calculated.